# Can you help me understanding the Stones game?

Tags: computer-puzzle, optimization, nim

I am trying to understand the Stones game stated [here](https://goo.gl/dLTqSI).

The stones game is a simple game, it is also a very old game which is unknown to almost everyone.

> The game starts with N stones and M players, the players are numbered
>   from 1 to M. The players play in turns, player number 1 plays first,
>   then player number 2 and so on until player number M plays, after this
>   player number 1 plays again and they keep playing until the end of the
>   game. For each turn, the players do the following 2 steps:
>
> 1. The player gets a chance to remove a stone, and he/she should remove a stone in this step if he/she decided to do so.
> 2. Regardless of the decision of the current player (whether or not he/she removed a stone in the first step), if this is not the first
>      turn and in the previous turn the player decided not to remove a stone
>      in his/her first step, then the current player must remove a stone in
>      this step (if in the previous turn the player decided to remove a
>      stone in his/her first step, then the current player must not remove a
>      stone in this step).
>
> This means in some turns a player might remove 0, 1 or 2 stones
>   according to the above rules. In this game, the player who removes the
>   last stone wins the game. Now you are given the total number of
>   stones, the total number of players and a player number and you are
>   asked to answer the following question: Is there a strategy for this
>   player to win the game regardless of the actions taken by the other
>   players in their turns?

In the sample example it is also stated that 2 players are playing with 2 stones and 2nd player can win the game regardless of the actions taken by the first player. How is it possible? A player can remove either 0 or 1 or 2 stones. If the first player removes 2 stones in his first turn 2nd player will not have any stones left to play then how 2nd player will be able to win?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first player is not allowed to remove 2 stones on his first turn. The description of step 2 says "if this is not the first turn". So the game goes like this.

- First player may remove either 0 or 1.

  - If first player removes 0, second player may now remove either 1 or 2.
  - (Second player will remove 2 and win.)
  - If first player removes 1, second player may now remove either 0 or 1.
  - (Second player will remove 1 and win.)

The second player always wins. (In the setup where N=M=2, that is.)

This wasn't part of the question, but let's work out what happens for 2 players in general. It's an *impartial* game in the sense of combinatorial game theory; a position is specified by saying how many stones are present (initially N) and whether the next player is choosing 0-or-1 or 1-or-2. And there's a little bit of tricksiness because reducing #stones to 0 is always a win even if the next player would otherwise have had the option of removing 0 stones; so we need to say that when #stones=0 there are no legal moves.

So, from (n,0-or-1) you can move to (n,1-or-2) or to (n-1,0-or-1) except that if n=0 you have no moves at all; from (n,1-or-2) you can move to (n-1,1-or-2) or (n-2,0-or-1). And after a bit of scribbling it becomes clear that the situation is as follows (easy proof by induction):

- For n=0 the next player loses (nim-value is 0).
- For n=1 the next player wins (nim-value is 2 for 0-or-1, 1 for 1-or-2).
- For n=2 the next player loses (nim-value 0) for 0-or-1; wins (nim-value 2) for 1-or-2.
- For larger *odd* n, the next player wins (nim-value 1) for 0-or-1 and loses (nim-value 0) for 1-or-2.
- For larger *even* n, the next player loses (nim-value 0) for 0-or-1 and wins (nim-value 1) for 1-or-2.

(In case you aren't familiar with the theory: the nim-value of a position is the size of the single pile in the game of Nim it's equivalent to, assuming "normal play" where the last player able to move wins; the nim-value of a position equals the smallest nonnegative integer that isn't the nim-value of any of the positions you can move to from it. A position is a win for the next player if its nim-value is non-zero and a loss if it's zero.)

Comment: The way I understand it, neither player 1 nor 2 can remove 2 stones in their first turn. (the first round)

Comment: I don't think that's right; my reading is that it's only on the very first play that step 2 isn't done. (Equivalently, we can pretend that in the initial position the non-existent previous player took the option of removing an extra stone.) If you don't allow player 2 to remove two stones on their first turn, then player 1 wins by removing 0; then player 2 has to remove 1; then player 1 removes 1 and wins. But the linked problem statement says (2 stones, 2 players) is a win for player 2.

Comment: As per my understanding, previous turn's Step 1 drives the current turn's step 2 then in first turn both the players will do only step 1

Comment: Yes, previous turn's step 1 drives current turn's step 2. In the first turn player 1 does step 1, then player 2 does steps 1 and 2. Otherwise you get an outcome for n=2 that doesn't match the description in the original problem statement.

Comment: (where, to be clear, by "the original problem statement" I mean the A2OJ page linked from the question.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a clearer statement of the rules. Each player has two options:

- Remove a stone on this turn.
- Remove a stone on the next turn.

This is because not removing a stone causes one to be removed next turn.

We now see that the game will last at most N+1 turns, because by then every player has removed a stone, whether or not they decided to delay or not. If the Nth player decided to remove a stone immediately (i.e. took the first option), then the game lasts N turns; if they delayed, it lasts N+1 turns.

Therefore, player N decides whether or not the winner is player N or N+1, so only player number N can force a win. It is possible for player N+1 to win, but only if player N decides for some reason to delay their stone removal.

If N is bigger than M, then the pivotal player is the remainder of N divided by M. A simple program to calculate whether player X can force a win is simply

```
def can_force_win(N,M,X):
     return N % M == X
```

Comment: The restatement might be easier to see by reversing the two parts of each turn.

Comment: 2 % 2 == 2 will return false.

Comment: 'return (N%M == 0 && M==X) || N % M == X;'

Comment: return (N-X)%M == 0

Comment: This is a very nice way of looking at it. [EDITED TO ADD:] For the avoidance of doubt, "this" means the answer, not my trivial tweak to the `return` statement in the previous comment.